# Two relative clauses together before the main verb

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses

I would like to ask if the following [sentence](http://www.mayonews.ie/component/content/article?id=11131:ballina-man-gets-suspended-sentence-for-driving-at-man) is grammatically correct because apparently two relative clause was used successively without any relative pronoun or whatever it is that sentence needs.

> An eighteen-year-old Ballina man *who drove his car at another youth
>   **resulting in him being flung onto the roof of the car*** was given a five year suspended sentence at last week’s sitting of Castlebar
>   Circuit Court.

If I disperse :

The following relative clause

> ...who drove his car at another youth resulting in him being flung onto
>   the roof of the car...

was used before the main verb "was given" in the sentence. While the part "man who drove his car at another youth" is the first relative clause simple and understandable,  I could not understand the second one "resulting in him being flung onto the roof of the car"  how the writer connected these two parts before main verb .

Comment: ***He** drove his car at a youth*. That action ***resulted in** the youth being flung onto the car roof*. Just the same as *The CEO resigned, resulting in a boardroom power struggle*, where the subject could be referred to as *The CEO who resigned, resulting in a boardroom power struggle, issued a statement last night explaining his actions*. What don't you understand?

Comment: The sentence would read more easily if the bolded phrase were set off by commas.  That would also be consistent with the fact that those words could be removed altogether without altering the main idea of the sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is understandable  now

Comment: There's only one relative clause, The clause _resulting in him being flung onto the roof of the car_ is just a result adjunct, not a relative clause. You could omit it with no loss of grammaticality; pretty much parenthetical really.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. *Resulting* is a participle, and normally a participle modifies a specific noun, usually the subject of a clause. However, in this case you could say **the participle modifies nothing specific, or it modifies the entire preceding clause** (*who drove his car at another youth*). It says something about the event described in the clause as a whole: the event described resulted in x. But there is no noun group like *this event* that it could modify, so it modifies the implicit event that took place.

This use of the participle is uncommon but perfectly acceptable. It is semantically aequivalent (though not syntactically aequivalent) to a relative clause:

> he drove his car at another youth, **which resulted** in him being flung onto the roof of the car

*Which* does not refer to *another youth*, nor to *he*, nor yet to *his car*: it refers to the entire first clause, in an indirect manner. The event that is described in the first clause is what resulted in him being flung onto the roof of the car. So *which* does not refer back to a specific word, but to something vaguer.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the participle, but participles can serve as adverbs, too, not just as adjectives.  That seems to be how it is used here: as an adverb modifying "drove".  It describes the result of that action.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that we could easily introduce a more specific *noun* to be the "subject" of the participle: *He [did something], which **action** resulted in [some outcome]*.

Comment: @PellMel: You could say that *resulting* is an adverb there. However, then what would the semantically similar *which* clause be (see my "quotation")? Would you say a *which* clause can be used adverbially? I'd rather not analyse it like that, I think. I'd rather assume an implicit noun and analyse the participle or *which* clause as modifying this noun. Consider also this example: *I saw the shape of her cat underneath the blankets, a big cat, resulting in a big lump.* Would you say *resulting...* is used adverbially here, too? If so, what verb does it modify exactly?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I suppose that is possible: but then what does *which* refer back to? It would still have to refer back to something, as it is a relative. Cf. *I experienced love for the first time, which emotion is the most powerful of all.* Here it refers back to *love*. I would say in your example you'd still have to say *which action* refers back to the whole previous clause, or to some implicit noun.

Comment: I can and do say that *resulting* is a participle, and that the associated participial phrase is adverbial in nature.  It is indeed semantically similar to your variant with *which*, even down to the ambiguity in the referent if "him".  Grammatically, however, "which resulted [...]" is a *bona fide* relative clause, not a participial phrase.

Comment: As for the cat under the blanket, the sentence is grammatically problematic for pretty much the reason you describe.  The lump results from the cat **being** under the blanket, not from seeing the cat's shape.  I would say that in that case "resulting [...]" is *trying* to be used adverbially, but failing because it has no referent -- neither any specific word nor in any sense any other phrase in the sentence.  In other words, it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @PellMel: 1. So is it possible for you, then, that a relative clause refers back to nothing specific? 2. How about if I add a dash: *I saw the shape of her cat underneath the blankets—a big cat, resulting in a big lump.*

Comment: @Cerberus, (1) No, I said nothing of the sort.  Your "which resulted ..." clause is *semantically similar* to the participial phrase, not grammatically equivalent.  A relative clause introduced by "which" can and here does refer to the whole independent clause with which it is associated -- not so a participial phrase.  (2) No, rewriting it with the dash does not make the sentence correct, nor really change the analysis very much.  It sounds a little better to my ear, but the "resulting [...]" phrase still has no sensible referent.  You could say "[...] making a big lump," though.

Comment: @Pell: 1. Okay, so a *which* clause can refer back to a whole clause, but then why can't a participle do the same? I'm still considering all options and I haven't decided yet which analysis I find the most useful; so far the three options are: a) it refers to the whole clause; b) it refers to an implicit noun; c) it is adverbial. 2. I have asked a few people in different chat rooms, and none saw a problem in my cat sentence, at least not with *resulting*. I'm not 100% sure what my own opinion is, but I am convinced that the kind of construction I used can in fact be found in natural language.

Comment: @Cerberus, I don't doubt that constructions similar to your cat sentence can be found in natural language, but that doesn't make them correct in any formal sense.  Nor does the opinion of random chat room participants.  Of course, my analysis to the contrary is not necessarily any more authoritative.

Comment: @Cerberus,  as for a *which* clause *vs.* a participle, the most significant difference is that the *which* itself is a pronoun that refers to the clause in question, and that's what connects the verb (ordinary past tense in that case) to the previous clause as a whole.  An adverb, on the other hand, or a participial phrase serving as one, must modify a verb, adjective, or other adverb, because that's the grammatical role of an adverb.  A participial phrase can also serve as an adjective, therefore modifying a noun, but the OP's sentence is not amenable to that interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> The following relative clause "...who drove his car at another youth resulting in him being flung onto the roof of the car..." was used before the main verb "was given" in the sentence.

Journalists are notorious for trying to cram as much information into their lead (often spelled "lede") as they possibly can, without much regard for whether the result is clumsy or not.

I would have (at least) edited this lead as follows:

> An eighteen-year-old Ballina man who drove his car at another youth, resulting in his being flung onto the roof of the car, was given a five-year suspended sentence at last week’s sitting of Castlebar Circuit Court.

I see that Cerberus has provided an excellent analysis (as usual) while I was writing this answer, so I'll say no more.